# Redux form initial values with Map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, immutable.js

i have a redux form and i want to set the initial values property to a Map and not an object. This is mandatory and i cannot change this :P
Therefore i set an initialValues Map like this:

```
export const initialValuesForm = (timeSlots, formValues) => {
  const initialValues = Map();
  const date = formValues[DATE_PICKER_FORM_FIELD] && formValues[DATE_PICKER_FORM_FIELD].startDate;
  const travelers = formValues[TRAVELERS_FORM];
  initialValues[POPUP_DATE_PICKER] = date;
  initialValues[TRAVELERS_FORM_SELECT] = travelers;

  return initialValues;
};
```

The formValues is an object with the values of another form from the state.
The very weird situation is that when i open the pop up with the form the values object and initial object are an empty object. When i change a value all the values are updated and are inside the Map. My mapStatetoProps function is this:
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    availability,
    locale,
    activityToBeAdded,
    popUpFormErrors,
    initialValues: initialValuesForm(timeSlots, searchFormValues)
  };
};
Why is this happening? Any ideas?